# escape mustache characters in slidify

Tags: mustache, slidify

I am using the following embedded code in my slidify. It's a code snippet from AngularJS code.

````
```html
<span>{{title}}</span>
<input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
<span>Name: {{name}}</span>
```
````

I have 2 questions.

1. Template placeholders ({{title}}, {{name}}) are disappearing in the final presentation. I would like them rendered as is with some syntax highlighting. How do I escape these ? I have tried `{r eval=F} and`r and ```js. They all have the same issue.
2. Where is the complete list of syntax highlighters I can use (other than ```r) with slidify.

I went through the slidify documentation and stack overflow questions and couldn't find any workable solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an undocumented feature of slidify. If you add the class RAW to any slide, it will not expand the mustache template within the content of the slide. By default, slidify does a double pass through the content. A slide of the RAW class does a single pass through, thereby leaving mustache templates in the content unresolved, as desired.

````
--- .RAW

```html
<span>{{title}}</span>
<input type="text" ng-model="name"></input>
<span>Name: {{name}}</span>
```
````

Comment: That worked. Thanks Ramnath for helping with that issue and also explaining the mechanism.

Comment: You are welcome. There are more treasures hidden in the Slidify source code, which I shall document slowly.